# While running the command chef-client -zr "recipe[twst-cookbook-test-recipe]" following warninng

Tags: chef-infra, warnings

While running the command `chef-client -zr "recipe[twst-cookbook-test-recipe]"` following warning shows?

```
WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.
Chef Infra Client, version 17.10.0
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
Infra Phase starting
Resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test-cookbook::test-recipe"]
Synchronizing cookbooks:
  - test-cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing cookbook gem dependencies:
Compiling cookbooks...
Loading Chef InSpec profile files:
Loading Chef InSpec input files:
Loading Chef InSpec waiver files:
Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Infra Phase complete, 0/0 resources updated in 02 seconds?
```

I want to create file using test-recipe code but it gives this warning I am new learner of chef what should I do.

Comment: The warning is because you don't have a client configuration file `client.rb`. You are running `chef-client` in "zero" mode, i.e. without a Chef server, so it doesn't matter. The cookbook is running fine. Once you add some code in recipe it should work.

Comment: still it dosen't work code in my recipe is file '/myfile' do content 'welcome'  action :create end

Comment: You should update this information in the question by editing it, also please show the cookbook structure.

Comment: Can you share your recipe code as well?